# Antenna mounting confusion from Datasheet

Tags: antenna, layout

I ordered a few samples of a particular antenna, because of the datasheet showed a rather peculiar layout - so I wanted to see what the actual component is and how it performs.

Antenna is Abracon's [ACAG0201-2450](https://abracon.com/datasheets/ACAG0201-2450-T.pdf).
Its datasheet suggests connecting it as such:
[image: Antenna layout parts from the datasheet]

As I received the components I cannot see any 'dual' pads on the feed entry side of the antenna (left side of the antenna) to make the connection for the feed line and also GND plane - it's all the same pad on the component!

So what, I am supposed to short feed line to GND? Max confusing. Or maybe the datasheet talks bollocks?

Maybe someone more experienced on the antenna topic can shed some light on this?

Comment: Are you saying that what you received is physically different to what you expected?

Comment: mm, not really. 
I guess, I wasn't expecting a single pad on the chip antenna, when footprint assumes two contact points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a look at the datasheet.

It seems you are supposed to let Abracon supply details to you when you use their [optimization service.](https://abracon.com/Support/Abracon-Antenna-Optimization-Services-and-Authorization-Form.pdf)

The datasheet is rather minimal on purpose.  You make an area of the specified size on your board (or a sample with just minimal traces and the antenna pads,) send the whole shebang (together with a few hundred bucks) to Abracon, and they return your modified board, application notes, and a custom part number.

When you build your own board, you order your parts according to the custom part number and do layout and circuitry according to the notes you received with your custom part number.

---

I can think of a couple of reasons for the "funny" footprint:

1. The final "custom part" you receive has different pads on it that will fit the given dimensions.
2. That apparent "short circuit" isn't a short circuit at the antenna's operating frequency.

In any case, it appears you **must** contact Abracon to actually make the cursed thing work.

Comment: 2. yup that's what I've heard from my colleague as well. So that's probably it.

I didn't get any hint for the custom part with this 'optimization service' from the datasheet. I've assumed that it's a plug'n'play component with provided layout considerations (not to mention necessary tuning)

The antenna providers usually All have this kind of 'service' where they try to sell tuning help and so forth, but quite frankly is mostly waste of time and money, unless in some few use-cases where self-dev is not an option.

I marked this as an answer as this covers my given answer and some more.

Answer (score 0):

ok, One possible answer, yet no clear reason, so not really very well solved, but clears some things:

I've now received a comment from one of my colleagues as well that, yes, that's how some of the antennas are mounted.

Even though there's an evident short from feedline to GND due to the chip antenna pad, the internal construction of the antenna would expect such connection via a specific footprint - as if some internal chip antenna structure would require that kind of a footprint.

So yeah, all in all, I probably won't be able to properly mount this on an existing layout, as this specific antenna needs this kind of quirky layout.

But maybe someone else can shine more light on it, why is that mounting so (even when the component looks similar to 0603) ?